# Get raw http request string for given data C++

Tags: c++, json, http, network-programming, httprequest

I'm looking for simple solution in `C++` to get raw http request string from given data, something like request parser.

For example, I'd like to have some kind of object, to which I can pass arguments like URL, Headers or Struct/JSON like this:

```
setMethod(httpRequest, POST);
setUrl(httpRequest, url);
setHeaders(httpRequest, headers);
setData(httpRequest, my_struct);
setContentType(httpRequest, "json");
```

And then have ability to retreive from it raw http request string fe:

```
POST /path/script.cgi HTTP/1.0
From: frog@jmarshall.com
User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 32
(...)
```

Have you ever heard how it can be acheived without writing it on my own?
I'd like to avoid parsing it on my own, having to deal with unclear strings and parsing structs

Comment: Library requests are off-topic on SO.

Comment: I have done this recently with using C++ sockets, it seems to be painful at first, but when you learn it, it's very powerful

Comment: I can't use sockets, it would be to painful for my whole project to switch to sockets

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius it does not have to be a library, it can be your own solution if you have one

Comment: I'm also In this journey, currentrly what helping me a lot is yhirose/cpp-httplib library on giuhub. Check it out.